# Validating a Dynamic SQL DELETE statement without executing the statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am attempting to validate some Dynamic SQL I have stored in a temp table and it could be any statement.

```
WHILE @counter <= (SELECT MAX(key) FROM @temp)
BEGIN
    SET @sqlVal = (SELECT value FROM @temp WHERE key = @counter);

    BEGIN TRY
        EXEC(@sqlVal);
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        INSERT INTO dbo.BROKEN_SQL SELECT * FROM @temp WHERE SQL_KEY = @counter;
    END CATCH

    SET @counter = @counter + 1;
END
```

This would work fine for me if I didn't also need to account for DELETE statements. I've tried to say:

```
BEGIN TRY
    SET NOEXEC ON;
    EXEC(@sqlVal);
    SET NOEXEC OFF;
END TRY
```

But this never allows broken SQL statements to the CATCH block. I've also tried PARSEONLY only but that doesn't work for me either. I just want to be able to confidently say that my lines of Dynamic SQL in @temp are valid without executing the SQL, and if they aren't then INSERT them into a table.

Comment: The problem is you have a batch-aborting statement. Turning off `XACT_ABORT` may help some of them. See also https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/270503/what-is-the-difference-between-set-noexec-on-and-set-parseonly-on

Comment: How did you identify that it *never allows broken SQL statements to the CATCH block*? You've set `noexec` to `on` so nothing has changed in the database. Put it inside your `try` block

Comment: Does it help you if you add a PRINT @sqlVal which then prints out what SQL is ran.  So you can replace the exec() with PRINT and just see what will be ran.

Comment: One way would be to begin a transaction and roll it back.

Comment: I have SQL statements that I set up as broken to test this, like "SLECT 10" and without NOEXEC ON it hits the CATCH block, and with the NOEXEC it doesn't.